# VS2010: Web Application code files being copied to bin/ directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish

This question relates to the "Publish" functionality of Visual Studio 2010.

I have an ASP.NET Web Application project.

All of my pages and code-behinds are in a directory called CADirectory/ under the application root.

When I publish it to my dev server, the .aspx & .cs files are being copied to bin/CADirectory in the app root; I'm expecting CADirectory/ to be copied up to the app root, and the compiled .dll to be coped to the bin/ directory.

Am I missing something? The project is definitely a Web Application, I'd post an image showing it but I Stackoverflow won't let me...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Properties of the `.aspx/.cs` files in VS2010. The Build Action should say "Compile" not "Content".

Comment: .aspx - content
.cs   - compile

I just set everything to compile, but the .aspx files are throwing errors - they can't compile anyway surely?

Comment: Sorry. the .aspx has to Content and .cs has to be compile. Let me know how you go.

Comment: I'll give it a bash and get back to you.

Thanks again!

Comment: Strange, its still behaving the same... when I publish to my local IIS instance (still using File System publish) it behaves correctly?